# Numerical optimization constraint results in answer that does not conform to constraint

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, mathematical-optimization, numerical

I am working on a constraint problem, trying to implement using Mathematica. My answer appears to work until I try to add additional constraints to select only a small subset of the available variables.

Update: download notebook file here for reference: https://www.dropbox.com/s/14nt4pf42lxteq3/ConstraintIssues.nb?dl=0

Here is the model that works:

```
NetV = -Abs[Sum[Ydata[[i]] * Subscript[y,i],{i,Length[Ydata]}]-
Sum[Xdata[[i]] * Subscript[x,i],{i,Length[Xdata]}]];

NetT =Sum[Ydata[[i]] * Subscript[y,i],{i,Length[Ydata]}] 
+Sum[Xdata[[i]] * Subscript[x,i],{i,Length[Xdata]}];

Objective = NetV / NetT;

DomainX = Table[Subscript[x,i],{i, Length[Xdata]}]; 

DomainY =Table[Subscript[y,i],{i,Length[Ydata]}]; 

DomainFull = Join[DomainX,DomainY]
```

Adding constraints that all selections from each of x and y are net zero (#negative = #positive), and that denominator always positive:

```
constraintFull = Join[{Apply[Plus,DomainX] == 0},{Apply[Plus,DomainY] == 0},
{DomainFull \[Element]Integers},{NetT > 0}];

result = NMaximize[{Objective,constraintFull},DomainFull]
```

I have modified the output to make it easier to read here, but the result is:

```
Object = -.000496983
X = {-2,-3,-1,-1,1,-1,-1,1,0,0,0,-1,0,2,-2,1,3,0,0,1,0,-3,2,2,2,0,0,-1,1,-7}
Y= {1,-1,0,1,-1,2,-1,0,-1,1,-2,1,0,-1,0,2,1,1,1,-1,1,0,1,0,1,4,0,2,-1,1,-1,0,
0,-1,-1,0,-2,1,0,1,0,2,-2,0,-3,2,-1,0,0,-1,0,0,0,1}
```

So far so good. Now suppose I want to add a constraint to pick 2 items each from X and Y, 1 each positive and 1 each negative. I add the following constraint:

```
extraConstraint = {Apply[Plus,Map[Abs,DomainX]] == 2, Apply[Plus,Map[Abs,DomainY]] == 2};

spurious = NMaximize[{Objective,Join[constraintFull,extraConstraint]},DomainFull]
```

This then returns......:

```
Objective = -.700899
X = {0,-1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,-1,-1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,-1,1,1,0,0,1,-1,0,0}
Y = {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,
0,0,0,-1,0,0,0,0,0,-1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,-1,0,0,0}
```

....which is definitely different, but also definitely *not* the behavior I expected. I think this must have to do with me confusing the underlying solver with my constraints; can anyone help me shed some light on this behavior, and perhaps recommend a better way to constrain the behavior I am looking for?

Comment: hard to see whats going on without `X/Ydata`

Comment: @agentp Each list of data is a series of float values:
Xdata = {130.136,127.017,123.847,120.74,117.654,17.3212,12.2567,15.1606,18.091,
18.8637,19.6379,20.2781,21.3306,22.1162,23.9692,27.9562,30.092,34.9059,
41.868,44.9632,105.523,111.358,114.457,49.8566,55.2547,58.9607,65.0852,
67.2575,69.4343,71.7475,74.0091,78.7811,81.2862,83.7683,88.993,91.6453,
94.2994,97.0199,99.8378,108.482,133.222,136.293,139.206,142.024,144.698,
147.188,149.484,151.492,153.185,154.605,155.604,156.217,156.437,6.59838,
6.34817}

Comment: Ydata = {65.2871,-64.4114,-63.4106,-62.5911,-61.6879,-14.9112,-11.1885,-
13.3237,-15.4669,-16.0089,-16.5367,-16.9031,-17.6987,-18.188,-
19.4147,-21.9318,-23.2108,-26.0488,-29.9731,-31.6503,-57.6092,-
59.4568,-60.5013,-34.1678,-36.8738,-38.5972,-41.4612,-42.463,-
43.419,-44.4837,-45.4267,-47.4429,-48.5042,-49.493,-51.6009,-
52.6344,-53.5947,-54.5949,-55.641,-58.6448,-66.1119,-67.0858,-
67.5406,-68.1755,-68.6569,-69.0303,-69.2147,-69.338,-69.2521,-
68.9165,-68.4481,-67.6894,-66.7615,-6.59412,-6.40199}

Comment: When i re-ran this notebook today, the spurious result came back with an error instead: FindMaximum::eqineq: Constraints in {list of constraints" are not all equality or inequality constraints. With the exception of integer domain constraints for linear programming, 
domain constraints or constraints with Unequal (!=) are not supported.

Comment: I should note that I am running this on the wolframcloud. In case that is relevant.

Comment: @agentp here is a link to download a .nb file that should make it easier to see: https://www.dropbox.com/s/14nt4pf42lxteq3/ConstraintIssues.nb?dl=0

Comment: I don't think there is anything fundamentally wrong with your code, just that you have posed a possibly intractable problem.  Try this: `FindInstance[Join[constraintFull, extraConstraint], DomainFull, Integers]` see if any combinations can be found to satisfy the constraints.

Comment: Every time I try to run the code you suggested, the wolfram engine for my notebook is terminated. So, I tried FindInstance[constraintFull, DomainFull, Integers]; no issues. However, FindInstance[constraintFull, extraConstraint, DomainFull, Integers] also causes the engine to terminate. I will see if there is some other way I can try to express these constraints

Comment: I actually let that `FindInstance` run a couple of hours with no results. (I guess wolframcloud just times out faster ).

Comment: So i have reformulated the problem to get rid of the Abs[ ] function in the constraints (notebook here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/4jet4t76fe5pysk/ReFormulate.nb?dl=0 ). I have created separate variables for the pos and neg possibilities each variable could take.  Then i added constraints, and tried to solve. I get the following result: "NMaximize was unable to generate any initial points satisfying the inequality constrain...the initial region specified may not contain any feasible points. Changing the initial region or specifying explicit initial points may provide a better solution"

Comment: I get a result but a non-integer result. I am not sure how to go about specifying an initial point; do i need an initial point for each variable?

Comment: My updated model along with additional questions here: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/94549/34071